# Usage of $Knowledge.Answer[2] or $Knowledge.Answer[3] in Dialogflow

Tags: dialogflow-es

While using Knowledge Base in Dialogflow, $Knowledge.Answer[1] is returning a response whereas $Knowledge.Answer[2] or $Knowledge.Answer[3] are not working. Any idea?

Comment: Please give a tick Mark if you find the answer appropriate

Answer (score 5):

According to googles Dialogflow [documentation](https://dialogflow.com/docs/agents/knowledge-connectors).
[image: Documentation]

You can see from the documentation that , Multiple responses are triggered only when you have multiple answers for the same question. And how do you give multiple responses?
Well this bugged me a lot too. But it is simple. Just give the same question twice with different answer or give a slightly different question with different answer.

Example(FAQ.txt / UTF-8):

```
How big is google?,Google is the universe.
How big is google?, It is the biggest in the world.
```

Now go to Dialogflow console and type in this question. And tada. You get two responses.

This is a sample response which I am getting for the question I asked.
[image: You can see that I am getting two responses]

So Knowledge.Answer[1] and Knowledge.Answer[2] and so on, is triggered only when there are multiple answers to that question.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

There's a [Bike Shop sample](https://github.com/dialogflow/fulfillment-bike-shop-nodejs) on Github that gives a walkthrough of how to get knowledge connectors setup for your agent via uploading a .csv file as the data source.